# Sum of cardinals without AC

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ and $B$ be infinite sets. To show $|A\cup B|=\max\{|A|,|B|\}$ we need AC.
Now let us assume $|A|<|B|$. Can we show $|A\cup B|=|B|$ *without* AC?

Answer (score 6):

In the absence of choice we may take $X$ be an [amorphous set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), let $A=X\times\{0\}$, and let $B=\big(X\times\{1\}\big)\cup\omega$. Suppose that $f:A\cup B\to B$ is a bijection. Let $C=f[A]$, $D=f[X\times\{1\}]$, and $E=f[\omega]$; then $\{C,D,E\}$ is a partition of $B=\big(X\times\{1\}\big)\cup\omega$.

Since $X$ is amorphous, so are $A$ and $X\times\{1\}$, so $E\cap\big(X\times\{1\}\big)$, $C\cap\omega$, and $D\cap\omega$ must be finite. Let $C_0=C\setminus\omega$, $D_0=D\setminus\omega$, and $F=\big(X\times\{1\}\big)\setminus E$; then $C_0,D_0$, and $F$ are amorphous, and $F$ is the disjoint union of $C_0$ and $D_0$, which is impossible. Thus, $|A\cup B|\ne|B|$.

Comment: I think the following is easier: Let $A$ be an amorphous set. Clearly $|A \times \{0\}| \leq |A \times \{1\}|$. However $|A \times \{0\} \cup A \times \{1\}| \neq |A \times \{1\}| = |A|$ because if there was a bijection $f$, then $A \times \{1\} = f(A \times \{0\}) \cup f(A \times \{1\})$. Hence $A$ is the union of two infinite disjoint subset.

Comment: @William: Yes, that’s easier; I just didn’t think of it right away, and I did think of the other example.

Comment: @William and Brian: Doesn't William's example show that without AC $x+x=x$ need not hold for an infinite cardinal $x$? Brian's example answers my question.

Comment: @Joel: Now that I look more closely, I see that William’s example doesn’t quite answer your question, because it has $|A|\le|B|$ rather than $|A|<|B|$.

Comment: @Brian: I don't see, why $E$ has to be finite. But independent of the finiteness of $E\cap (A\times\{0\})$ the partition of the amorphous set $A\times\{0\}$ into the disjoint infinite sets $C_0$ and $D_0\cup F$, where $F$ can also be finite, which is impossible.

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @Joel: $E$ isn’t finite, but $E\cap\big(A\times\{0\}\big)$ has to be finite because if it weren’t, you could easily construct an injection of $\omega$ into $A\times\{0\}$ and hence into $A$.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, I meant $E\cap (A\times\{0\}$, sorry. But why can't there be an injection of $\omega$ into $A\times\{0\}$ --- as long as the complement of the image is finite?

Comment: @Joel: Suppose that $\varphi:\omega\to A$ is injective. Let $E=\{2n:n\in\omega\}$. Then $\varphi[E]$ and its complement are both infinite, so $A$ can’t be amorphous.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, of course. Thank you!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott A nitpick, but for a general set $A$ it is not necessarily true that $A$ and $A\times\{0\}$ are disjoint.  I imagine using $A\times\{0\}$ was a way to get a "copy" of $A$ disjoint from $A$.  But that can be assumed by replacing the first $A$ with $A\times\{1\}$ and then renaming it as $A$ again.

Comment: @PatrickR: Many thanks! You are of course correct.

Answer (score 5):

The axiom of choice is in fact equivalent to the assertion that $A+B=\max\{A,B\}$, for every two infinite cardinals.

To see the non-trivial implication, consider $A$ to be any set and $B=\aleph(A)$, the Hartogs number of $A$.

On the other hand, if we already assume that $A<B$, things may be a bit trickier, it requires *some* choice but not everything.

- If there exists an infintie Dedekind-finite set (a set that is larger than any proper subset), then clearly $1<A$, but $A+1$ is strictly larger than $A$.
- On the other hand, consider Sageev's model in which every infinite set has the property that $A+A=A$. In this model, however, there is a countable family without a choice function so not even countable choice holds.

  Suppose $A<B$, then there is a subset $B'\subseteq B$ such that $A\sim B'$. In particular there is a bijective map from $A\cup B$ into $B$ which maps $A\cup B'$ onto $B'$. Therefore $A+B=B$.

So without the axiom of choice we may have models in which this is true, and others in which this is false.